# How to put custom post types on front page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, theme-development, pre-get-posts, frontpage

I'm trying to create a portfolio with WordPress using a Custom Post Type to display my projects.  Each project I want to display on my static front page with a featured image as a thumbnail, and by clicking on a thumbnail would take me directly to the project.

How do I post Custom Post Types to the static front page?  I want to show only the latest 6 posts, and then I'd have a link to the rest via my navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you've registered a CPT called `wpse_242473_custom_post_type` you can use this to put 6 recent posts of that type onto your static front page (or anywhere).  You can use a shortcode or a template tag and the function should work for both.

It's a modification of some code I use in a lot of sites.  Put it in your theme's `functions.php`. Modify the HTML I've used to suit yourself, of course.

I've added a twist that I've been meaning to try for a while, so if it chokes on you let me know and I'll test it properly.  What I've added is a full set of optional arguments that let the same function work, I hope, for both a shortcode and a template tag.  You can either put `[recentposts]` into the visual editor on any page, or you can put `<?php wpse_242473_recent_posts(); ?>` into any template of your theme.

To put it into the template for your static front page, edit (or create) the template `front-page.php`.  This will be automatically selected for your static front page, without you having to select it within the page edit screen.

```
function wpse_242473_recent_posts( $atts = null, $content = null, $tag = null ) {

    $out = '';

    $args = array( 
        'numberposts' => '6', 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'post_type' => 'wpse_242473_custom_post_type' ,
    );

    $recent = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    if ( $recent ) {

        $out .= '<section class="overview">';

        $out .= '<h1>Recent Projects</h1>';

        $out .= '<div class="overview">';

        foreach ( $recent as $item ) {

            $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
            $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
            $out .= '</a>';
        }

        $out .= '</div></section>';
    }

    if ( $tag ) {
        return $out;
    } else {
        echo $out;
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'recentposts', 'wpse_242473_recent_posts' );
```

It's a straightforward retrieval of the posts you want.

The `foreach` loop builds your HTML and then the conditional at the end either returns the HTML, if you've used a shortcode, or echoes it if your calling the function as a template tag.

What a lot of articles on the web don't show you is that third argument passed to all shortcode handlers.  When you use the shortcode it contains the shortcode name, so a handler could in theory handle multiple shortcodes.  In this case we're using it to tell whether the function was indeed called as a shortcode handler or not.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit: This answer was written before I realised the OP has a static front page.**  I've left it here in case it's useful to anyone else and added a second answer for the static front page case.

This will add your custom post type to the home page main loop:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_242473_add_post_type_to_home' );

function wpse_242473_add_post_type_to_home( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your_custom_post_type_here') );
    }
}
```

Checking `is_home` makes sure we're on the main blog "home" page and `is_main_query` ensures that we don't inadvertently affect any secondary loops.

If you only want your custom post type and not ordinary posts, then remove `post` from the array of post types.

There are some incorrect articles on the web which treat this action as a filter.  It's not, it passes the query by reference so that you can set query args directly.

Comment: Any idea how to exclude custom posts with no category?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow following steps:
1)Create a template of your CPT(Custom post type)
2)Place following codes in that template; replace CPT with your CPT.
3)Open a new page and publish a new page selecting  this template from the right hand side.
4)Finally, go to setting then click on reading then select front page under A static page.

Codes:

```
<?php
/**
 *Template Name:CPT
 * @package CPT 
 * @since CPT  1.0
 */ 
get_header(); 

global $paged;  
    if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    } elseif( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'CPT',
        'posts_per_page'=>6,
        'paged'         => $paged,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                      <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) {?>
                                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                           <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>  
                                          </a>
                                        <?php }
                                      ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```