# output custom post types on front-page.php

Tags: custom-post-types

I came across this thread [How to put custom post types on front page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242473/how-to-put-custom-post-types-on-front-page) (**thanks to @Andy Macaulay-Brook for the code**)

and was able to use that code in my front-page.php to output portfolio items via twentysixteen child theme. It did work by putting `<?php wpse_242473_recent_posts(); ?>` into **front-page.php** however its not working when I am putting **[recentposts]** into the visual editor on **'work' page** which is using **front-page.php**

I don't have much knowledge about PHP just some basics but out of curiousity I tried to google some parts of the function and what they mean and then modify the code slightly and remove parts related to shortcode (as shortcode was not working). Now I removed below parts and its working for me.

I have 3 questions:

1. Do I need to use shordcode or this function can be used without shortcode portion?
2. Did I use `echo $out;` correctly to output the result of the function to the browser?
3. I already have my html markup for this page. Can I use this function to output my html into the browser or I should hardcode some html actually into my `front-page.php`?

**Below are the changes I made to this function:**

```php
$atts = null, $content = null, $tag = null
```

(I removed those shortcode arguments)

I changed this part

```php
if ( $tag ) {
   return $out;
    } else {
   echo $out;
 }
```

to this

```php
    echo $out;
```

I also removed `add_shortcode( 'recentposts', 'wpse_242473_recent_posts' );`

So my current code looks like this

```php
    function wpse_242473_recent_posts() {

      $out = '';

      $args = array( 
          'numberposts' => '6', 
          'post_status' => 'publish', 
          'post_type' => 'portfolio' ,
      );

      $recent = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

      if ( $recent ) {

          $out .= '<section class="overview">';

          $out .= '<h1>Recent Projects</h1>';

          $out .= '<div class="overview">';

          foreach ( $recent as $item ) {

              $out .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item['ID'] ) . '">';
              $out .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $item['ID'] ); 
              $out .= '</a>';
          }

          $out .= '</div></section>';
      }


        echo $out;


    }
```

added Custom Post Type code for review (portfolio-type.php)

```
<?php

/*
* Sets 'Portfolio' CPT (Custom Post Type) in admin screen and .
* This template is loaded to functons.php in child theme via 'require_once' function        
*/



//set thumbnail size and image size

function portfolio_thumb_and_image_size () {

  set_post_thumbnail_size( 280, 210, true); //thumb
  add_image_size ('screenshot', 720, 540); //image

}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'portfolio_thumb_and_image_size', 17);

//add custom post type


function portfolio_register() {

  $args = array(

        'label' => __('Portfolio'),
        'singular_label' => __('Project'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui'=> true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail') 
      );

      register_post_type('portfolio', $args);

}

add_action ('init', 'portfolio_register');


//add custom taxonomy

register_taxonomy ('project-type', array ('portfolio'), array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Project Types', 'singular_label' => 'Project Type', 'rewrite' => true));

//add custom fields


function portfolio_meta_box() {

add_meta_box ('project-meta', 'Project Options', 'portfolio_meta_options',  'portfolio', 'side', 'low');

}

add_action("admin_init", "portfolio_meta_box");

function portfolio_meta_options(){

      global $post;

      if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
      $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
      $link = $custom ['project-link'][0];
?>

<label>Link:</label><input name="project-link" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
<?php
 }

//save custom meta boxes when the post is saved


function save_project_link (){

      global $post;

      if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE )  {
         return $post_id;
      }

      else  {

        update_post_meta ($post->ID, 'project-link', $_POST['project-link']);
      }
}

add_action ('save_post', 'save_project_link');

//customize admin columns

//add custom columns via filter hook (make columns available on the edit posts page)
function project_register_columns($columns) {
  $columns = array(
      'cb' => '<input type=\'checkbox\' />',
      'title' => 'Project',
      'description' => 'Description',
      'link' => 'Link',
      'type' => 'Type of Project',

  );
  return $columns;

}

add_filter('manage_edit-portfolio_columns', 'project_register_columns');

//add content to custom columns: 'description' 'link' 'type'
function add_columns_content ($columns) {
    global $post;
    switch ($columns)
    {

        case 'description':
            the_excerpt();
            break;

        case 'link':
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom['project-link'][0];
            break;

        case  'type':
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'project-type', '', ', ','');
        break;

    }

}

add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_columns_content');



function wpse_242473_recent_posts() {
  $frontpage_args = array( 
      'numberposts'   => '6', 
      'post_status'   => 'publish', 
      'post_type'     => 'portfolio' ,
  );
  $recent = wp_get_recent_posts( $frontpage_args ); ?>
  <section class="overview">
      <h1>Recent Projects</h1>
      <div class="overview">
      <?php if( $recent ) :
          foreach ( $recent as $item ) : ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $item->ID ); ?>">
                  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->ID ); ?> 
              </a>
          <?php endforeach;
      endif; ?>
      </div>
  </section>
}
```

content of front-page.php

```
<?php 

get_header();

?>


<main class="home">

    <h1>this is front-page.php</h1>

    <?php wpse_242473_recent_posts(); ?>

    <!-- porfolio items go here ––>


</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend avoiding helper functions such as  `wp_get_recent_posts`, they're their for historical reasons and tend to cause more problems than they're worth  due to the little changes they make trying to be helpful. In this case, a standard `WP_Query` loop would cut out the middle man and be more in line with what most developers do, as well as what tutorials and WP code uses

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Tom J Nowell. If you can give me a link or two to those tutorials that would help. I am new to WordPress and PHP and its very easy to find wrong info on the web with bad practices hence I am asking if you can refer me to some reliable tutorials

Comment: Aside from checking how recent a tutorial is, if you need to fetch/display posts, use `WP_Query`. If you want to change what WP shows in the main loop, use the `pre_get_posts` filter. For how to use a WP function, always check the official dev docs at developer.wordpress.org, and the comments on their pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, completely re-written answer based on previous attempts and some suggestions from the comments (which I agree with as I've never used `wp_get_recent_posts()` myself...

Assuming that everything for your custom post type is working correctly (*I didn't test it though*) then just use the following for your front-page.php.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main class="home">
    <h1>This is front-page.php</h1>
    <?php
    $fp_portfolio_args  = array(
        'post_type'         => 'portfolio',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6
    );
    $fp_portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $fp_portfolio_args );
    if( $fp_portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <section class="overview">
        <h2>Recent Projects</h2>
        <div class="overview">
        <?php while ( $fp_portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $fp_portfolio_query->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ); ?> 
            </a>
            <?php $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'project-link', true ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">View Project</a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback Tony Djukic. I am not sure I fully understand few lines from this function. Say is it a standard practice just to put html tags inside the function? like I am seeing here h1, section, divs, etc...

Comment: Also why do we need to wrap 'foreach' statement inside 'if'? Also what is $item->ID ? My understanding anything with $ sign is a variable which kind of serves as a container for other things, however, I don't understand what is the purpose of -> after variable name..

Comment: I added to my answer to address your follow-up questions.  Did you try the code?  Full disclosure, I've never used wp_get_recent_posts() but when I checked online it's basically just a prepared wp_query().  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/#comment-1825  You can see in that example that the HTML is just placed into the function.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the detailed explanations. I just tried your code and it didn't work.

Comment: Sure. The error I am getting is 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file'

Comment: Yes, I removed <?php at the beginning and the ?> at the end. Still not working. I am using two files: functions.php and portfolio-type.php.  functions.php uses require_once('portfolio-type.php'); The error message I mentioned happens after I put your code into portfolio-type.php (which has all CPT related functions) and try to view my work page in the browser which is trigerred by front-page.php.

Comment: Actually, if you want to just post your front-page.php in your question, with a comment line showing where you want the portfolio items to load, I can address this for you using WP_Query as @Tom J Nowell mentioned in his comments.

Comment: I edited my question and posted both portfolio-type.php and front-page.php.

Comment: I've re-written the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Your code is working now. I would need to take sometime to understand how WP_Query works as I already have my html and css for this particular page so I would need to try to tweak it to accomodate my html and css.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry it took so long, I supposed I should have just showed you how I would have done it in the first place instead of trying to sort out a helper function I don't ever even recall using.  I added some more code to the answer to show you how you could add more to the output so it could work with the HTML you've already written.  Basically the `while()` statement is similar to a foreach.  So anything that sets up the container to display all the portfolio items, goes outside the `while()`, but everything that pertains to EACH specific item (repeats) goes inside the `while()`.